# What is the purpose of tempdb in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need a clarification about `tempdb` in SQL Server and need some clarifications on following things

1. What is the purpose of its?
2. Can we create a own `tempdb` and how to make refer the own `tempdb` to own database?

Comment: Read this [tempdb MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms190768.aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx

Comment: Thank you both to refer the link... I have gone through the document and got some clarity about tempdb. One more doubt raised for me, if my clarity about tempdb is correct, then when we create a database in sqlserver that created database uses this tempdb for executing queries right. How may I change my own database to refer my own tempdb to execute queries and all. If my clarity is wrong please tell me...

Comment: Why would you need another temporary database?

Comment: Our customer asked this as a requirement to us like our **application db** must  use our own tempdb instead of default tempdb available in sql server. So I just got confused how to keep own tempdb for our application db.

Comment: Set separate SQL server instance for your customer then.

Comment: @BhuvaneshWaran, does your customer know what they are asking? Do they handle extremely sensitive data?

Answer (score 3):

[FROM MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx)

The tempdb system database is a global resource that is available to all users connected to the instance of SQL Server and is used to hold the following:

1. Temporary user objects that are explicitly created, such as: global
   or local temporary tables, temporary stored procedures, table
   variables, or cursors.
2. Internal objects that are created by the SQL Server Database Engine,
   for example, work tables to store intermediate results for spools or
   sorting.
3. Row versions that are generated by data modification transactions in
   a database that uses read-committed using row versioning isolation
   or snapshot isolation transactions.
4. Row versions that are generated by data modification transactions
   for features, such as: online index operations, Multiple Active
   Result Sets (MARS), and AFTER triggers.

Operations within tempdb are minimally logged.

This enables transactions to be rolled back. tempdb is re-created every time SQL Server is started so that the system always starts with a clean copy of the database.

Temporary tables and stored procedures are dropped automatically on disconnect, and no connections are active when the system is shut down. Therefore, there is never anything in tempdb to be saved from one session of SQL Server to another. Backup and restore operations are not allowed on tempdb.

Answer (score 2):

TempdB is a system database and we cant create system databases .Tempdb is a global resource for all databases ,which means temp tables,table variables,version store for user databases...all will use tempdb..This is a pretty basic explanation for tempdb.Refer to below links on how it is used for other purposes like database emails,..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1: It is what it says. A temporary storage. FOr example when you ask for DISTINCT results, SQL Server must remember what rows it already sent you. Same with a temporary table.

2: Makes no sense. Tempdb is not a database but a server thing - ONE TempDB regardless how many database. You can change where it is and how it is (file number, size) but it is never related to one database (except obviously if you only have one database on a SQL Server instance). Having your own Tempdb is NOT how SQL Server works. And while we are at it - no need to ever make a backup (of tempdb). When SQL Server starts, Tempdb is reinitialized as empty.

And, btw., this would be obvious if you would bother with such things as being borderline competent. Which includes for me reading the documentation of every major technology I work with once. You should consider this to be something to adopt because it is the only way to know what you are doing.